# facebook login give me already authorized this app without automatic returning to the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

My app should implement login with facebook but I have noticed that every time I want to login the facebook tell me you are already authorize this app , the question if I already authorized the app the facebook should return automatically without pressing the okey button as I saw in other applications ?

see the attached image
[image]

Comment: redelet your appli, sign out from facebook and retry

Comment: still the  same after the deletion then logout / login

Comment: Running in the simulator? Because the simulator behaves a little different than the actual device.

Comment: I have the same scenario in the phone

Comment: Use [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed my problem by doing the following steps :
1- login to your facebook as admin to your app.
2- go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID/summary.
3- go to **settings** > **basic** > **Native IOS app**
4- set the **Configured for iOS SSO:** to enabled

Comment: I am not able to find Configured for iOS SSO options. there are Deeplinking and Facebook login only available

Comment: In my case if I login with facebook then after logout again i login it goes to facebook app and again back to my app.If I want to omit this redirect.What can be done?

Comment: this should happen to get the permission from the facebook app or the facebook website if you donot have app, you have another option for not open the app or the website is to use the native iOS facebook integration

Comment: @Roshni Ios SSO means Single Sign ON (SSO) .Please see this

Comment: enabling SSO didnt change anything for me

Answer (score 2):

In iOS/Android the FBAccessToken's expiration time is up to 60 days. When you do FBLogin in your app you get the access token. once you get the token you should not do login again(otherwise you will be prompted **already authorized this app** since your app has already been given an access token earlier which is not expired ). You should reuse the **unexpired access token.**

Like this :

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
  print(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().userID)
  print(currentAccessToken().tokenString)
//OR call the *FBGraphRequest*
 }
```

Note: for in-App browser login (SVC: Safari View Controller)

see more: 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/
and
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/4.9/class/FBSDKLoginManager/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your app has the proper URL Prefix in your Build Settings.  Also make sure that the URL Prefix matches your Facebook ID/URL Prefix in the Facebook developer app.

**Edit:** Your issue is probably that the access_token is expiring so it's have to re-ask for permissions.

This will happen if your application did not request offline_access permissions.  In the newer SDK offline_access is deprecated and you now have to extend the access_token.

See this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#extend_token

Comment: From where I can edit this , I follows the facebook developer documentation to implement this and the only what i entered is the fb_APPLICATION_ID I did not enter urls !!

Comment: Did it fix it?  If so please mark as answer.  If not, what was the result?

Comment: it is not fix the app !  would you explain the solution ? because as i say before i did not enter any URLs or some thing like this !

Comment: Go to this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso  And look for this: Modify the app property list file.  This will show you how to add your URL Prefix to the Build Settings PLIST.

Comment: Oh you mean this , I added it before and it is still added

Comment: Did you try extending the token?  Checking for it on load?

Answer (score 1):

As this Question is already answered , but i would like to add another helpful answer for `Swift 3.0` :

While using FB Login in Swift , i having issue and i previously did this way:

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .systemAccount
```

As this uses , System account to check user is authorized for login or not . Unless you logout and login through different user , application shows same "Already authorized" message in place of Fresh login . So i used this way and this trick does the work :

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .web.
```

This show Login Screen after logout.
Hope this helps to solve this issue.

Feel free to comment . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if there is a current session before logging in with `FBSDKLoginManager`. Do not use `[loginManager logout]` before logging in.

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) 
 {
      NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);
      // Now get details using graphpath. 
 } else {
     // login with permissions using FBSDKLoginManager and get details using graphpath in completion

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a open bug at facebook.com

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/190389531089978

But the bug only appears at android, ios works fine.

(btw. same behavior in the foursquare and spotify android app - check it out)

Comment: but I have the same problem in the ios ! and i found the same problem in the **trip adviser**  ios application

Comment: can you reproduce the bug on ios in foursquare app?

Comment: today i tried a few apps on ios with facebook sign in. Spotify, Trip Advisor and our own App works fine. Sorry, i cant reproduce the bug on ios.

Comment: I can not reproduce it on the foursquare app!

Comment: the same issue appears in the android foursquare

Answer (score 0):

Run your iOS FB application into device not simulator it works fine, and didn't shows the already authorized screen.
Thank you.