# After logout ios sdk shows that You are already authorized not showing me the login page again in safari

Tags: ios, ios9, facebook-ios-sdk

It's not showing me the login page again in **safari**. How to get read of this error?
Thanks in advance.

I have tried by clearing the cache and stored information of the user from "iphone" settings safari clear history, it worked but what if I want this to be done form my code, or any alternate solution for this problem. If you are having then just let me know.

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42375054/3400991