# FB latest sdk ios logout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello all I'm not able to logout FB using latest sdk, its showing "already authorized" even after logout. Here is my code for logout.

```
login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser;

if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

    [login logOut];
    [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
    [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
    NSLog(@"Logged out of facebook");
    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:www.facebook.com"]];
    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: you need to delete your permision also

Comment: Can u add some code for deleting permission

Comment: Try by closing tocken information of current session
FBSession* session = [FBSession activeSession];
 [session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

Comment: FBSession not available in recent sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Its because may be you logged in through Safari. Now when you try to log from the app its actually logging out but in the safari the session still exists.

Comment: Yes its true, but I have written code for deleting cookies.

Comment: I don't think its `http`. it should be `https`. Besides, have you checked the `facebookCookies` array if the array count returning 0 or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have replaced http with https still getting same issue, even facebookCookies array count is 0, what is the proper solution ,pls help.

Comment: still array count 0

Comment: Then I think you should you webview instead of safari.

Answer (score 0):

I think login/logout(based on access token) and authorizing your iOS application to use your FB account are two different things. And this link confirms, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/33780346/3719248

**Edit:**

You want to do this, when you run this `[login logOut];` your user also gets logged out from safari browser. If this is correct I don't think this could be achieved. FBSDK uses `SFSafariViewController`, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31311184/3719248).

As a developer you don't have access to cookies of `SFSafariViewController` due to [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31311184/3719248).

Currently cookies your are getting for `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` if implemented and used. Which I think is not your case

Comment: so what will be the solution?

Comment: @Peter as I mentioned, you don't have access to cookies of SFSafariViewController. Run this same case i.e login via FB , logut , login again via FB on Instagram. IMO this "already authorized" is pretty normal with FBSDK