# Facebook iOS SDK 4.x: changing the user to log in

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm upgrading Facebook SDK from 3.x to 4.x and need to log in as different Facebook users to my application (game) in order to check if FB requests work correct.
In 3.x login dialog switched to FB application, so I could change the user in the FB application and got new credentials for my login. Now I only got "You have already authorised..." message in a Safari-view login dialog.
I changed user in FB application several times as well as uninstalled my application in order to clean its local cache - nothing helps. My application always logs in as User 1, even if I logged in as User 2 in FB application.
How can I login as a different user (clear saved token, got a credentials dialog or something else)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888582/facebook-login-give-me-already-authorized-this-app-without-automatic-returning-t
check this

Comment: @Muhammad Zohaib Ehsan: Nothing from that post helps

Comment: I think fb takes user of Safari, you need to log in fb from Safari and exit the user

Comment: @PeDuCKA: That works, thanx! Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to log in fb from Safari and exit the user =)

Comment: User is not logged in Safari for me (trying simulator) but is still auto logged in the app :/